# Class vs. Public Class

Tags: c#, class, public

What is the difference between:

```
namespace Library{
    class File{
        //code inside it
   }
}
```

and:

```
namespace Library{
   public class File{
       //code inside it
   }
}
```

So what will be the difference between **public class** and **class**?

Comment: Its like a government body keeping nuclear launch codes secret versus wearing a tee-shirt that has the launch codes on it.

Comment: Note that it's good practice to always add access specifiers rather than relying on language defaults.  This helps cases where people don't know what it is, don't remember, mistakenly believe that it is something that's not correct, believe that you just forgot to add it (and add something other than the default), etc.  It takes so little effort, and it really helps readability.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I don't know, I'm sure somewhere there's a t-shirt with "000" written on it. (Which was once actually the code to one level of security on US missile launch, though only a level most of the people thought was pointless anyway).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Without specifying `public` the class is implicitly `internal`. This means that the class is only visible inside the same assembly. When you specify `public`, the class is visible outside the assembly.

It is also allowed to specify the `internal` modifier explicitly:

```
internal class Foo {}
```

Comment: What does assembly mean @driis? Can you explain what it means to be isnide the same assembly vs outside?

Answer (score 24):

The former is equivalent to:

```
namespace Library{
    internal class File{
        //code inside it
   }
}
```

All visibilities default to the least visible possible - `private` for members of `class`es and `struct`s (methods, properties, fields, nested classes and nested `enum`s) and `internal` for direct members of `namespace`s, because they can't be private.

`internal` means other code in the same assembly can see it, but nothing else (barring friend assemblies and the use of reflection).

This makes sense for two reasons:

1. You should be consciously making things use the least visibility possible anyway, to strengthen your encapsulation.
2. If they defaulted to `public` you could accidentally make something public that should be private or internal. If you accidentally make something not visible enough, you get an obvious compile error and fix it. If you accidentally make something too visible you introduce a flaw to your code that won't be flagged as an error, and which will be a breaking change to fix later.

It's often considered better style to be explicit with your access modifiers, to be clearer in the code, just what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all `class`es (and all types for that matter) are `internal`, so in order for them to be accessible from the outside (sans stuff like `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`) you have to make them `public` explicitly.

Comment: Nope, they're internal. Everything inside the classes are private by default though.

Comment: -1, because the answer is wrong. Then removed -1 after you edited the answer :-)